Why setting GRUB to disable NX protection is not working?
I am trying to disable NX protection on my linux (6.8.11-686-pae) to run a program that I need to test. But after setting GRUB to disable it, I am still getting:
dmesg | grep NX
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active

grep -m1 nx /proc/cpuinfo
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht nx rdtscp constant_tsc xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch pti fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 bmi2 invpcid rdseed clflushopt arat md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities

grep noexec=off /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.11-686-pae root=UUID=f7f891fb-a9b6-42e2-8480-43ead6c59728 ro noexec=off noexec32=off splash

My /etc/default/grub is set like this:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR= `lsb release -i -s 2> /dev/null Il echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“”    
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noexec=off noexec32=off"

And also checked while booting with the e key (to see the current boot options: noexec=off noexec32=off are in the right place.

Consult with your kernel sources. The feature might have been disabled.

Thank you for your answer, Mr. @ArtemS.Tashkinov Could you be more specific about "kernel sources"? And, before searching that path, could you anticipate what other alternative you imagine would be possible to tweak it? (i.e. "Recompile the kernel with certain flag/s?" (how? No idea, I never did it). I would need some concrete clue to continue. Thx!
